# Android setText in asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, udp, settext

I'm working on a UDP program but I'm having trouble with applying `setText` in my `asynctask`.  Basically on the UDP server, I just ask to input a port and then the server should connect to the localhost and the port.  A `TextView` in the middle of the layout says "Currently not connected" and when I click connect to a port, I want it to change to "Connected."  However, it is not doing anything.  I tried searching around but was unable to come up with a solution.  If anyone can help me figure out the problem that would be greatly appreciated.

My Thread asynctask code: 
EDIT: took `setText` out of doinbackground.  However, `setText` still is not functional.

```
public class ServerThread extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    TextView chatbox;
    TextView amiconnected;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        chatbox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        amiconnected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        PORT = Integer.parseInt(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString());
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        //open socket at specified port on the local host
        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
            //listening

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            socket.receive(packet);
            text2 = new String("Now you're connected.");
            //convert received message to string
            text1 = new String(buf, 0, packet.getLength());

            //get client address from received packet
            //client_addr = packet.getAddress();
            //byte[] message = new byte[1024];

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return text2;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String text2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(text2);
        chatbox.setText(text2);

    }
```

EDIT: My entire UDP Server code

```
    package com.example.udpcomm;

import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Server extends Activity{
    int PORT;
    DatagramSocket socket;
    InetAddress client_addr;
    String text1;
    String text2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_server);
        //chatbox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Button connectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectserver);
        connectButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                new ServerThread().execute();
            }
        });
    }
    //parameter string port (converted into int)
    //onprogressupdate (inputting string (?) into TextView)
    //on postexecute return null (?)
    public class ServerThread extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        TextView chatbox;
        TextView amiconnected;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            chatbox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            amiconnected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            PORT = Integer.parseInt(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString());
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            //open socket at specified port on the local host
            try {
                socket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
                //listening

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                socket.receive(packet);
                text2 = new String("Now you're connected.");
                //convert received message to string
                text1 = new String(buf, 0, packet.getLength());

                //get client address from received packet
                //client_addr = packet.getAddress();
                //byte[] message = new byte[1024];

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return text2;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String text2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(text2);
            chatbox.setText(text2);

        }   

    }


}
```

Comment: You need to read the docs. Half the point of AsyncTask is to manage the interaction between the UI thread and the worker thread. Don't do `setText` in `doInBackground`. You can do it in `onProgressUpdate` or perhaps `onPostExecute` as necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to move your `UI` actions to the `onPreExecute()` or the `onPostExecute()` methods as `doInBackground` cannot touch the `UI`. I would suggest you return the string or value you need to put in the `TextView` from the `doInBackground` method and then apply it to the `TextView` in the `onPostExecute()` method. Reference [AsyncTask Description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried following the changes you suggested since it seemed the most straightforward with what I already had.  However, I still do not seem to be getting a change in the "Connected" TextView, which is the text2 value.  Do you happen to see anything else problematic in my code? (although I have text1 defined I am not using it atm for simplicity's sake).

Comment: Can you post your current code now, let me see if I can identify anything else :)

Comment: I just posted my entire UDP Server code (incase it's not just the thread that's the problem).  Thanks for taking a look at it

Comment: Have you tried just declaring your views in the main activity definition?

Comment: Hm I just tried it but I ended up getting a FATAL ERROR, unable to instantiate activity

Comment: I commented out my server code and just tried outputting text2 and it works! thanks for your help!